# Correct way to store generated swift client library to artifactory

Tags: swift, github, artifactory

I am creating a Swift Client Library using openapi tools with Github actions. I need to upload it to Jfrog artifactory. I am not familiar with Swift, so not sure what would be the correct way to upload the client library, so can be used easily when it gets pulled

My Current Workflow file;

```
name: Generate Swift Client Library

on:
  pull_request:
    branches: [ "main" ]

permissions:
  contents: read
  actions: read
  checks: write

jobs:
  generate-swift-client:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    name: Example
    steps:

    - name: Checkout
      uses: actions/checkout@v3
     
    - name: Generate Swift Client
      uses: openapi-generators/openapitools-generator-action@v1
      with:
        generator: swift5
        openapi-file: openapispec.yaml
  
    - name: Login to JFrog   
      uses: docker/login-action@v3
      with:
        registry: my.jfrog.io
        username: ${{ secrets.ARTIFACTORY_USERNAME }} 
        password: ${{ secrets.ARTIFACTORY_PASSWORD }}`
```